# How to map DOM tags to dictionary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I need to find a way to map all the tags that appear in a DOM to key:value dictionary (With structure of TagName:Attributes).
I have to do that with Javascript or JQuery code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI JS has no dictionary type, although you can mimic the same behaviour using an object.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [Javascript: How to loop through ALL DOM elements on a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256339/javascript-how-to-loop-through-all-dom-elements-on-a-page) you can list all elements of the document using getElementsByTagName():

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     // Do something with the element here
}
```

and looking at this [Creating a .net like dictionary object in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787754/creating-a-net-like-dictionary-object-in-javascript) a dictionary can be built like:

```
var dictionary = {};//create new object
dictionary["key1"] = value1;//set key1
var key1 = dictionary["key1"];//get key1
```

or further, if you want to add specific methods:

```
function Dictionary(){
   var dictionary = {};

   this.setData = function(key, val) { dictionary[key] = val; }
   this.getData = function(key) { return dictionary[key]; }
}

var dictionary = new Dictionary();
dictionary.setData("key1", "value1");
var key1 = dictionary.getData("key1");
```